# Disable legend based on another legend click - angular nvd3 chart

Tags: angularjs, charts, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I would like to disable a legend(breached95) based on the click of another legend(var95) in nvd3 chart.

[image]

Below script fires the legend click event which gives the click legend values but unable to disable another legend based on this event.  How to achieve the behavior?

```
 callback: function(chart) {
                       chart.legend.dispatch.legendClick = function(val, i){
                            if(val.originalKey==="VaR95Total"){
                                //hide 'breached95' legend
                            }
                        };
                    },
```

Comment: Do you mean the legend item or the entire series? If you want to disable another series, just modify the series data to have disabled: true

Comment: Disable. entire series. But currently there is no way to do it dynamically in the 'legendClick' event.

Comment: Why don't you just mutate the data and set disabled to true on the series? You haven't provided a JSFiddle/Plunkr so difficult to provide further feedback.

e.g. var newData = data.map((dataset) => {
  if (dataset.key === 'series-to-disable') {
    dataset.disabled = true;
  }
  return dataset;
});